# base href='/' not work when i use angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, radix, location-href

I am using angular and `angular-ui-router` to navigate. The version of angular is `1.6.4` and angular-ui-router is `0.4.2`. It is auto-comment when i add  in the head (I find this in the firefox console Inspector. It is `<!--<base href="/">-->`). Meanwhile, console tell me:`Error:$location::nobase`. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @tanmay Thanks vary much. I am a newer and i am not familiar with the format. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

So uncomment the `<base href="/">` for html5 mode.